# PHP Notice Custom Format

Tags: php, error-handling, php-7

When PHP emits a `PHP Notice` to the log, it contains the file name and the line number where the problem occurred. In the case of a large application, this often isn't enough to reproduce the problem. What would really help is some additional information, most obviously the URL that was being called at the time this notice occurred.

Is there a way to customize the `PHP Notice` message in PHP >= 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your own error handler and catch the notices then log the message with whatever information you need. The code below produces the following the PHP error log file.

> [27-Feb-2019 13:55:09 America/New_York] 8 Undefined variable: hello
>   from URI /customnotice.php

```
function myErrorHandler($errno,$errstr, $errfile, $errline) {

    if ($errno == 8) {  // this is a notice
        error_log($errno . ' ' . $errstr . ' from URI ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }
}

$old_error_handler = set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");

echo $hello;  // will throw a notice for testing
```